# How to make NestJS file read .env values

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS project with a .env file that holds some values. I'm having problems to read these values from the my *TypeORM* config file.

**typeorm.config.ts**

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as config from 'config';

const dbConfig = config.get('db') as any;

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: dbConfig.type,
    host: process.env.HOST_NAME || dbConfig.host,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || dbConfig.port,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME || dbConfig.username,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || dbConfig.password,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME || dbConfig.database,
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
    synchronize: dbConfig.synchronize
};
```

On the `imports` of my module I have this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig)
   ]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is imported on `import * as config from 'config'`?
Can you share it?

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be import { config } from 'dotenv';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use useClass with TypeOrm and inject config service in db options classes.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({ useClass: TypeOrmConfigService})
```

**typeorm.config.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }
  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      host: this.configService.get<string>('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
      type: 'mysql',
      port: this.configService.get<number>('DB_PORT', 3306),
      username: this.configService.get<string>('DB_USERNAME', 'local'),
      password: this.configService.get<string>('DB_PASSWORD', 'pwd'),
      database: this.configService.get<string>('DB_NAME', 'db'),
      entities: [__dirname + '/../*/.entity.{js,ts}'],
      retryAttempts: 3,
      extra: {
        connectionLimit: 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```